# Pass "DirectoryInfo" object into Controller from a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to MVC2 and was wondering if it was possible to pass an object into a Controller Action from a View?

e.g.
I've created a ViewModel containing a list of DirectoryInfo objects and pass this to my Index view.

In the view, I loop through all of the DI objects and for each one create an ActionLink.

```
<%:Html.ActionLink(linkText: subfolder.Name,actionName: "Reports",
                routeValues: new {folder=subfolder}, htmlAttributes:null )%>
```

but in my Reports action, the "folder" is always null?

```
 public ActionResult Reports(DirectoryInfo folder)
    {
      //folder is always null here
```

Is this type of thing possible, or does the routingValue always have to be a primitive?

*(ps. I have searched StackOverflow and t'internet and although I can find people asking the same question, I can't find a solution*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DirectoryInfo` is a complex object and I don't think you will be able to put it directly into HTML. You need to send something simple like path of directory or file from which controller can construct the required `DirectoryInfo` again.

Comment: Thanks - I'd started off that way with the Path, so I'll carry on.  Just one of those things you think about!